# Unable to post data on Jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My code to post data to server is like this

```
  $('#btn').click(function () {

        var myarray = [];
        $("#DocumentList input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {
            myarray.push($(this).attr('uniqueid'));
        });
        alert(myarray);
     
        $.ajax({
            url: "url",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "text",
            data: myarray,
            success: function (response) {
               
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
```

on alert I am getting the data I want to post to server, But when I inspect the call on Chrome,I can see that data is not getting posted (screenshot added below). What can be the reason for this behavior?
[image]

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - OP states the data `myarray` is there - not sure how seeing HTML or server side code would help this problem :p - at a guess, the fact that `data` is an `Array` may be the problem

Comment: Yeah, good point :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery does not expect you to pass an array of strings to `data`.

It can't process that usefully.

Typically you would pass an object of name: value pairs:

```
data: { something: myarray }
```

… which will URL encode it with the `something[]` extended syntax introduced by PHP.

You will need to make sure the encoding you send matches whatever the server expects though.